# Comparing two CSV files in Python when rows have multiple values

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, compare

I have two CSV files that I want to compare one looks like this:

```
"a" 1   6   3   1   8
"b" 15  6   12  5   6
"c" 7   4   1   4   8
"d" 14  8   12  11  4
"e" 1   8   7   13  12
"f" 2   5   4   13  9
"g" 8   6   9   3   3
"h" 5   12  8   2   3
"i" 5   9   2   11  11
"j" 1   9   2   4   9
```

So "a" possesses the numbers 1,6,3,1,8 etc. The actual CSV file is 1,000s of lines long so you know for efficiency sake when writing the code.

The second CSV file looks like this:

```
4

15

7

9

2
```

I have written some code to import these CSV files into lists in python.

```
with open('winningnumbers.csv', 'rb') as wn:
    reader = csv.reader(wn)
    winningnumbers = list(reader)

wn1 = winningnumbers[0]
wn2 = winningnumbers[1]
wn3 = winningnumbers[2]
wn4 = winningnumbers[3]
wn5 = winningnumbers[4]

print(winningnumbers)

with open('Entries#x.csv', 'rb') as en:
    readere = csv.reader(en)
    enl = list(readere)
```

How would I now search cross reference number 4 so wn1 of CSV file 2 with the first csv file. So that it returns that "b" has wn1 in it. I imported them as a list to see if I could figure out how to do it but just ended up running in circles. I also tried using dict() but had no success.

Comment: Not sure I follow your logic, what is wn1 supposed to be?

Comment: wn1 (winning number 1) would be the first number in the second csv file so it would be the value 4.  The first list value.

Comment: So you want to find which rows contain certain numbers?

Comment: But b does not have 4 in it? Also do repeats matter?

Comment: Your are right, that was accident was supposed to type C. Repeats dont matter.

Comment: Run the code in my answer and see if we are on the same page

Comment: I would add some full expected output as there are numerous ways to interpret what should actually happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having duplicate numbers seems illogical but if you want to get the count of matched numbers for each row regardless of  index then makes nums a set and sum the times a number from each row is in the set:

```
from itertools import islice, imap
import csv
with open("in.txt") as f,open("numbers.txt") as nums:
    # make a set of all winning nums
    nums = set(imap(str.rstrip, nums))
    r = csv.reader(f)
    # iterate over each row and sum how many matches we get
    for row in r:
        print("{} matched {}".format(row[0], sum(n in nums
                                                 for n in islice(row, 1, None))))
```

Which using your input will output:

```
a matched 0
b matched 1
c matched 2
d matched 1
e matched 0
f matched 2
g matched 0
h matched 1
i matched 1
j matched 2
```

presuming your file is comma separated and you have a number per line in your numbers file.

If you actually want to know which numbers if any are present then you need to iterate over the number and print each one that is in our set:

```
from itertools import islice, imap
import csv

with open("in.txt") as f, open("numbers.txt") as nums:
    nums = set(imap(str.rstrip, nums))
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for row in r:
        for n in islice(row, 1, None):
            if n in nums:
                print("{} is in row {}".format(n, row[0]))
        print("")
```

But again, I am not sure having duplicate numbers makes sense.

To group the rows based on how many matches, you can use a dict using the sum as the key and appending the first column value:

```
from itertools import islice, imap
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
with open("in.txt") as f,open("numbers.txt") as nums:
    # make a set of all winning nums
    nums = set(imap(str.rstrip, nums))
    r = csv.reader(f)
    results = defaultdict(list)
    # iterate over each row and sum how many matches we get
    for row in r:
        results[sum(n in nums for n in islice(row, 1, None))].append(row[0])
```

results:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>,
 {0: ['a', 'e', 'g'], 1: ['b', 'd', 'h', 'i'], 
 2: ['c', 'f', 'j']})
```

The keys are numbers match, the values are the rows ids that matched the n numbers.

Comment: I get a syntax error on line 2 when running this code. This is a little more advanced than what I know so I am not sure why this syntax error is occurring.

Comment: Are you using python2 or 3?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7, sorry should have mentioned before hand.

Comment: Run the second code, the first has python3 syntax only, are you trying to match any or all numbers?

Comment: If I wanted to create some kind of a list to any entries which matched 1 number where assigned to a list and an entries that matched 2 was added to a different list etc. What is the best way of doing that?

Comment: Use the sum as the key for a duct and use a list as the value appending the row letter to the list. Use a collections.defaultdict

Comment: Thanks I will attempt to figure this out now.

Comment: Im not having much success, I think more learning is in order. How would you code this, perhaps once I see it in code I will understand better.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Really helping my learning. You have helped me a lot on two posts now so thanks. I have really started to grow to love python and am eager to learn more. Perhaps we could talk on Skype or something and you could give me some pointers/advice? Just a though :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you want to find the first index (or all indexes) of numbers in entries that are winning. If you want it, you can do that:

```
with open('winningnumbers.csv', 'rb') as wn:
    reader = csv.reader(wn)
    winningnumbers = list(reader)

with open('Entries#x.csv', 'rb') as en:
    readere = csv.reader(en)
    winning_number_index = -1 # Default value which we will print if nothing is found
    current_index = 0 # Initial index
    for line in readere: # Iterate over entries file
        all_numbers_match = True # Default value that will be set to False if any of the elements doesn't match with winningnumbers
        for i in range(len(line)):
            if line[i] != winningnumbers[i]: # If values of current line and winningnumbers with matching indexes are not equal
                all_numbers_match = False # Our default value is set to False
                break # Exit "for" without finishing

        if all_numbers_match == True: # If our default value is still True (which indicates that all numbers match)
            winning_number_index = current_index # Current index is written to winning_number_index
            break # Exit "for" without finishing
        else: # Not all numbers match
            current_index += 1 

print(winning_number_index)
```

This will print the index of the first winning number in entries (if you want all the indexes, write about it in the comments).

Note: this is not the optimal code to solve your problem. It's just easier to undestand and debug if you're not familiar with Python's more advanced features.

---

You should probably consider not abbreviating your variables. `entries_reader` takes just a second more to write and 5 seconds less to understand then `readere`.

---

This is the variant that is faster, shorter and more memory efficient, but may be harder to understand:

```
with open('winningnumbers.csv', 'rb') as wn:
    reader = csv.reader(wn)
    winningnumbers = list(reader)

with open('Entries#x.csv', 'rb') as en:
    readere = csv.reader(en)
    for line_index, line in enumerate(readere):            
        if all((line[i] == winningnumbers[i] for i in xrange(len(line)))):
            winning_number_index = line_index
            break
    else:
        winning_number_index = -1

print(winning_number_index)
```

The features that might me unclear are probably `enumerate()`, `any()` and using `else` in `for` and not in `if`. Let's go through all of them one by one.

---

To understand this usage of enumerate, you'll need to understand that syntax:

```
a, b = [1, 2]
```

Variables `a` and `b` will be assigned according values from the list. In this case `a` will be 1 and `b` will be 2. Using this syntax we can do that:

```
for a, b in [[1, 2], [2, 3], ['spam', 'eggs']]:
    # do something with a and b
```

in each iteration, a and b will be 1 and 2, 2 and 3, 'spam' and 'eggs' accordingly.

Let's assume we have a list `a = ['spam', 'eggs', 'potatoes']`. `enumerate()` just returns a "list" like that: [(1, 'spam'), (2, 'eggs'), (3, 'potatoes')]. So, when we use it like that,

```
for line_index, line in enumerate(readere):
    # Do something with line_index and line
```

`line_index` will be 1, 2, 3, e.t.c.

---

`any()` function accepts a sequence (list, tuple, e.t.c.) and returns `True` if all the elements in it are equal to `True`.

Generator expression `mylist = [line[i] == winningnumbers[i] for i in range(len(line))]` returns a list and is similar to the following:

```
mylist = []
for i in range(len(line)):
    mylist.append(line[i] == winningnumbers[i]) # a == b will return True if a is equal to b
```

So `any` will return True only in cases when all the numbers from entry match the winning numbers.

---

Code in `else` section of `for` is called only when `for` was not interrupted by `break`, so in our situation it's good for setting a default index to return.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I ran the second code and got a return of -1. I assume that is because nothing has matched all 5 indexes? Thanks for the tip I wont do that in future.

Comment: Yes, if there is no mistake in my code. I'll comment the more advanced code and change variable names according to my reccomendation.

Comment: Got it I see. Thanks for adding the comments really helps in understanding. Let me add another line to the CSV file where all 5 numbers match.

Comment: @Joshua, are you looking for any number or all to match as they are two completely different things?

Comment: It would be great if I could create something where it showed all that matched. So for example x matched 2 numbers, z matched 3 etc etc. So no matter how many it matches it will be displayed as a "winner".

Comment: @Joshua, but in your code you have repeated numbers i,e 15 and 2, is that actually possible?

Comment: @Joshua It won't be very different, I'll redo my examples.

Comment: Sure. They are all just random numbers between 1-15. The first CSV file is supposed to emulate a real user entering into some kind of draw. So user a has picked the values  1,6,3,1,8. The second csv file are just 5 random numbers between 1-15. I wanted a way to say if user x has matched n amount of numbers they have won.

Comment: @Joshua, but if a user picks 1,2,3,4,5 and the random numbers are 1,1,1,1,1 does that mean they win? Having duplicate numbers in a draw seems illogical Both answers here also presume you must match the same order that they appear i.e `1,2,3,4,5 != 1,3,2,4,5` which also seems illogical for a number draw

Comment: They would have then matched one number. And won the "prize" associated with one matched number to put it into context. That is why I though to split the winning numbers up as wn1 etc. So It could just parse the csv file and check to see if a user has matched wn1, then do the same for wn2 etc.

Comment: @Joshua, you still did not answer the question, do the numbers index in each row have to match the order the are seen in the numbers file?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, it is more memory efficient (in python3, yes) because it uses iterators, so it doesn't have to store all the sequence in memory.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, iterators are more memory-efficient then sequences + I use iterators instead of sequences => it works faster. It looks like simple logic to me. Do you refer to me creating `winningnumbers` list? Yes, I wasn't sure if `csv.reader` returned lists and not strings, thank you for clarifying that it does.

Comment: @IlyaPeterov, if it returned strings do you realise what `list(some_string)` would do? Also you create a list using range regardless, there is literally zero memory difference in both your code examples.

Comment: Glad to see I have started a little debate ahah :) @PadraicCunningham I have decided on the logic behind it. The winning numbers cannot be duplicates. So my second csv file is useless now. The order at which people match does not matter. Its just about how many numbers they match.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, yes, that is my mistake, too. Range returns something like an iterator =>  it doesn't store all the numbers in memory => it doesn't consume more memory then necessary.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, anyways, we're talking about storing or not storing 5 int's in memory, which is probably not such a big deal. The main thing I meant when I said that it was more memory-efficient, is that it didn't store all the entries file in memory, unlike the code in the original question, which is probably unclear from my answer, which is, again, my mistake.

Comment: @IlyaPeterov, you need xrange for python2, range will create a list so when you use it inside the genexp your list is first created. Only in python3 range returns an immutable sequence which generates values as needed, if you want to compare elements at corresponding indexes itertools.izip or using enumerate would be the way to go

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, but at the moment I submmited the edit with memory-efficiency claim it wasn't clear whether OP uses python2 or python3. I should probably edit my answer and  change range to xrange.

Comment: `if all(n == winningnumbers[i] for i in enumerate(line,1))`

Comment: on another note your `all` would always return False `"b"` != any_digits,use enumerate as above passing 1 as the start

Comment: @Joshua, then using a set to store the nums is the way to go, to get `n `random unique nums use `random.sample`, then get the user to choose `n` nums making sure to remove each num after they have picked one before  their next choice